# Regex replace in List Comprehension in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list

Does anyone know how to use re.sub in Python with list comprehensions.

Im using the following,

```
>>> a = ["N","!","1","abc"]
>>> [(re.sub(r'(h|N|!|N|1)', r"'\033[91m'\g<1>'\033[0m'", 'x')) for x in a]
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```

As you can see Im only getting x returned as the list elements.

Thanks,

Comment: I see you're doing `for x in a`, but you never actually use the `x` variable. Is that intentional?

Comment: Unquote 'x' and it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kevin commented, you didn't used `x`, but used the string literal `'x'`:

```
>>> [(re.sub(r'(h|N|!|N|1)', r"'\033[91m'\g<1>'\033[0m'", x)) for x in a]
["'\x1b[91m'N'\x1b[0m'", "'\x1b[91m'!'\x1b[0m'", "'\x1b[91m'1'\x1b[0m'", 'abc']
```

**UPDATE**

The regular expression can be expressed using character class (`[....]`) if the components are all single-character strings.

```
>>> [(re.sub(r'([hN!1])', r"'\033[91m'\g<1>'\033[0m'", x)) for x in a]
["'\x1b[91m'N'\x1b[0m'", "'\x1b[91m'!'\x1b[0m'", "'\x1b[91m'1'\x1b[0m'", 'abc']
```